# Sending contents of file to server - python socket

Tags: python, sockets

When doing the put command I am getting this error. I can't seem to figure out why.

line 41, in 
    data = client.recv(1024)
error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Here is my client code:

```
import socket
import sys
import os

HOST = 'localhost' 
PORT = 8082 
size = 1024

def ls():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
    s.connect((HOST,PORT))
    s.send(userInput)
    result = s.recv(size)
    print result
    s.close()
    return

def put(command):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.send(command)
    string = command.split(' ', 1)
    input_file = string[1]
    with open(input_file, 'rb') as file_to_put:
        for data in file_to_put:
            s.sendall(data)
    s.close()
    return


def get(command):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.send(command)
    string = command.split(' ', 1)
    input_file = string[1]
    with open(input_file, 'wb') as file_to_get:
        while True:
            data = s.recv(1024)
            print data
            if not data:
                break

            file_to_get.write(data)
    file_to_get.close()
    s.close()
    return

done = False
while not done:
    userInput = raw_input()
    if "quit" == userInput:
        done = True
    elif "ls" == userInput:
       ls()
    else:
        string = userInput.split(' ', 1)
        if (string[0] == 'put'):
            put(userInput)
        elif (string[0] == 'get'):
            get(userInput) 

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.close()
print "Closing connection."
```

And server code:

```
import socket
import os
import sys

host = '' 
port = 8082 
backlog = 5 
size = 1024

serverID = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
info = 'SERVER ID: {} port: {}'.format(serverID, port)
print info

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
s.bind((host,port)) 
s.listen(backlog)
done = False

#Loop until client sends 'quit' to server
while not done: 
    client, address = s.accept() 
    data = client.recv(size)

    print "Server received: ", data
    if data: 
        client.send("Server Says... " + data)
    if data == "quit":
        done = True
    elif data == "ls":
       data = os.listdir('c:\\')    # listing contents of c: drive
       client.send(str(data))
       print data
    else:
        string = data.split(' ', 1)
        data_file = string[1]

        if (string[0] == 'put'):
            with open(data_file, 'wb') as file_to_write:    # opening sent filename to write bytes
                while True:
                    data = client.recv(1024)                
                    if not data:
                        break
                    file_to_write.write(data)               # writing data
                    file_to_write.close()                   # closing file
                    break
            print 'Receive Successful'
        elif (string[0] == 'get'):
            with open('C:\\' + data_file, 'rb') as file_to_send:
                for data in file_to_send:
                    client.send(data)
            print 'Send Successful'

    client.close()
s.close()
print "Server exiting."
```

Comment: Does `host` need to be `'localhost'` in the server code?

Comment: yes, to run it on my one machine

Comment: I mean maybe you need to change `host = ''` to `host = 'localhost'` in your server code.

Comment: I tried that and got the same error.